# Gear hotkeys: which is which

Tags: warframe

If I assign **Q** for the first one, which is the item I'm going to activate?

What about the next ones (2,3,4,5,6,7,8)? I think it's sorted clockwise though.

[image: hotkeys]
[image: gear]

Comment: Why not test it out for yourself, see what happens

Comment: I would recommend finding it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so, here's how it goes:

[image: rightorder]